# Bokeh plot not updating when using CheckBoxGroup

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have been at this for hours now. I am trying to plot the spread (and deaths) of Covid-19 in different countries of the world (it shows new cases, total cases, new deaths and total deaths in different tabs). I want to allow the user to choose which countries they want to see using the CheckBoxGroup widget from Bokeh but my plot isn't updating. Additionally, when debugging, I noticed that the update function only updates when there is a new selection (or so it seems). When I select a country, if I print the src data from the update function, the data from the new country is present (but is not plotted). However, when I unselect a country, the data from that country is still present after it is supposed to have been updated.

I don't know if the use of groupby creates a problem (I haven't seen any working examples with groupby, I tried using MultiLine but I'm not quite sure I understood the purpose).

PS : If anyone knows how to format  CheckBoxGroup to have columns it would also be great, but it's far from being a priority right now.

Thanks in advance !

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from os.path import dirname, join


from bokeh.io import push_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_notebook,figure,curdoc

from bokeh.models import CategoricalColorMapper, HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, Panel,CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup, Slider, RangeSlider, Tabs, MultiSelect

from bokeh.layouts import column, row, WidgetBox
from bokeh.palettes import all_palettes

from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.application import Application   





def make_dataset(select_countries):
    prep_data={}
    for i,group in enumerate(select_countries):
        group[1].set_index('date', drop=True, inplace=True)
        data=group[1].reindex(all_days)
        data["location"].fillna(method='backfill',inplace=True)
        data.fillna(value=0,inplace=True)
        data['color']=color_list[i]
        data.reset_index(inplace=True)
        prep_data[group[0]]=data
    return ColumnDataSource(prep_data)

def make_plot(src):

    p1 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=600,x_axis_type='datetime',title = 'Chart of new cases over time',
              x_axis_label = 'Date', y_axis_label = 'Number of new cases')
    p2 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=600,x_axis_type='datetime',title = 'Chart of total cases over time',
              x_axis_label = 'Date', y_axis_label = 'Number of total cases')
    p3 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=600,x_axis_type='datetime',title = 'Chart of new deaths over time',
              x_axis_label = 'Date', y_axis_label = 'Number of new deaths')
    p4 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=600,x_axis_type='datetime',title = 'Chart of total deaths over time',
              x_axis_label = 'Date', y_axis_label = 'Number of total deaths')
    for group in src.data.values() :
        plot1=p1.line(x='index',y='new_cases',source=group,color=group['color'].values[0],legend="location")
        plot2=p2.line(x='index',y='total_cases',source=group,color=group['color'].values[0],legend="location")
        plot3=p3.line(x='index',y='new_deaths',source=group,color=group['color'].values[0],legend="location")
        plot4=p4.line(x='index',y='total_deaths',source=group,color=group['color'].values[0],legend="location")

    p1.legend.click_policy = 'hide'
    p2.legend.click_policy = 'hide'
    p3.legend.click_policy = 'hide'
    p4.legend.click_policy = 'hide' 

    tab1 = Panel(child=p1, title="new_cases")
    tab2 = Panel(child=p2, title="total_cases")
    tab3 = Panel(child=p3, title="new_deaths")
    tab4 = Panel(child=p4, title="total_deaths")


    tabs = Tabs(tabs=[ tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4 ])


    return tabs

def update(attr, old, new):
    # Get the list of countries
    select_countries_labels=[country_selection.labels[i] for i in country_selection.active]
    #print(select_countries_labels)
    select_countries=[countries_selected for countries_selected in countries
                  if countries_selected[0] in select_countries_labels]

    new_src = make_dataset(select_countries)
    #print("new countries")
    #print(new_country_list.data)
    # Update the source used the quad glpyhs
    src.data.update(new_src.data)
    #=new_country_list.data
    #print(country_df.data)


df=pd.read_csv(join(dirname(__file__),'full_data(2).csv'), encoding='utf-8',parse_dates=["date"])
countries=df.groupby("location")
l=countries.describe(include="all")
all_days=pd.date_range(l.loc['World']['date']['first'],l.loc['World']['date']['last'],freq='D')

# Countries and colors

color_dicts=[list(colors.values()) for colors in list(all_palettes.values())]
color_list_int=[color for color_sublist in color_dicts for color in color_sublist]
color_list_dup=[color for color_sublist in color_list_int for color in color_sublist]
color_list=list(set(color_list_dup))
color_list.sort()

available_countries = list(set(df['location']))
available_countries.sort()


# Countries to plot
country_selection = CheckboxGroup(labels=available_countries, 
                                  active = [0,1])
country_selection.on_change('active', update)

# Initial carriers and data source

select_countries_labels=[country_selection.labels[i] for i in country_selection.active]
initial_countries=[countries_selected for countries_selected in countries
                  if countries_selected[0] in select_countries_labels]

# Prep the data
src = make_dataset(initial_countries)

# Make the covid plot
p1 = make_plot(src)

# Put controls in a single element
controls = WidgetBox(country_selection)

# Create a row layout
layout = row(controls, p1)


curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "covid"
```

Comment: Please provide a data sample.

Comment: Oh right ! I got my data from here (https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/full_data.csv),  the only change in the code would be to remove the (2) from the line `df=pd.read_csv(join(dirname(__file__),'full_data(2).csv'), encoding='utf-8',parse_dates=["date"])` @EugenePakhomov

Comment: You're using `ColumnDataSource` in `make_dataset` incorrectly. CDS is for only for storing data that's for direct consumption by Bokeh. Each column must be a list like thing, not a data frame.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov Oh ok, thanks. I'm not quite sure how I should modify the code in this case though...I based my code off of working examples but maybe I missed a nuance in the code. How come do I still get a plot if my `make_dataset` function is incorrect then?

Comment: You get a plot just because it happens to work, that's all. And as you can see, your update function doesn't work, for that exact reason. The callbacks have to change something of which Bokeh is aware. I.e. something that ends up in the document tree.